# Android studios app Login failed and app crashes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am getting the following errors when I try login to my app using firebase as well as the app crashing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 31052
java.lang.NullPointerException: usernameInput must not be null
    at com.example.newsapp.LoginActivity$login$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

my activity_login.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newslogo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="432dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="345dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/registerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:text="@string/register_here"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="237dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

does anyone know what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Also does anyone know how to display profile details onto an fragment. The details I want is from the firebase database.

Thanks

Comment: can you also please share the xml file also.

Comment: just added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the userInput & passwordInput, Your xml ids are not the same as you used in `findViewById`

You need to make sure they are the same.

You can use the below `findViewById` instead in login activity that has Ids given from the layout

```
....
private fun login(){
    val loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.loginButton)
    val usernameInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)
    val passwordInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password)

//...
```